# Alter the Synonyms in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

What is the alter command to alter the below synonym.
How to alter this Synonyms .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM "scott"."ADDL_INFO_GRANT" FOR "user"."ADDL_INFO_GRANT";
```

I want to alter this `"user"."ADDL_INFO_GRANT"` to `"user1"."ADDL_INFO_GRANT"`.

want to change the schema name for `FOR` in the Synonyms ?

After running the alter command  the query should be like below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM "scott"."ADDL_INFO_GRANT" FOR "user1"."ADDL_INFO_GRANT";
```

Comment: You have already answered your own question.

Comment: I am asking about the alter command for the query?

Comment: `Alter sequence` statement doesn't change schema name. Use `create or replace` statement.

Comment: YES, CORRECT, GOT THE SOLUTION . BY USING create or replace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **REPLACE** keyword is to replace it with the current changes. You don't need any ALTER statement. You just need to **compile** it again.

And it not only applies to **SYNONYM**, but also to other **PL/SQL stored objects** like functions, procedures, packages etc.